# WPF UserControl Binding for Position in Parent

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm already familiar with property bindings in XAML. Now I've created a custom UserControl which is dragable within a [DragCanvas](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DraggingElementsInCanvas.aspx). How can a create a binding for the position (left/top) within the DragCanvas?

Kind regards.

[1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DraggingElementsInCanvas.aspx): [Dragging Elements in a Canvas](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DraggingElementsInCanvas.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{Binding ElementName=this, Path=(DragCanvas.Left)}
```

and

```
{Binding ElementName=this, Path=(DragCanvas.Top)}
```

Comment: Ok. I set the binding on a label within my user control, but it should be on the user control itself. Thank you.